# Laravel Image validation allowing pdf file

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am having issues with the file type image validation in *Laravel 4*. The image validation works if the file mime type is other than `application/pdf`. Please see the code below:

**Controller**:

```
$rules = array(
    'title' => 'required|min:3',
    'content' => 'required|min:3',
    'navigation_title' => 'required|min:3',
    'image' => 'image'
);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

The view form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. The validation works fine if I try to upload txt file, HTML file etc. but validator passes if I upload a PDF file. Do I need to add a mime type validation as well?

Comment: What is the fully qualified class name of `Validator` in your question?

Comment: It is the default Validator which ships with Laravel 4. 'Illuminate\Validation\Validator'

Comment: If that's the case, pdf is excluded, take a look in the source. If you're in doubt create a testcase for `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` that fails with your issue and send a pull-request to the project and create an issue that explains your issue.

Comment: The file which I was trying to upload was exceeding the max upload file size.